# Java BigDecimal CompareTo Not Working with Small Numbers

Tags: java, max, bigdecimal, compareto

I need to compare extremely small numbers for an artificial intelligence project. Here is my method:

```
private static int maximum(BigDecimal a1, BigDecimal a2){
    System.out.println(a1);
    System.out.println(a2);
    if (a1.compareTo(a2)<0){
        return 1;
    }else{
         return 0;
    }
```

Here is my output with the return value printed 3rd:

```
0E-917
0E-912
0
0E-918
0E-921
0
0E-932
0E-933
0
```

Is there any way to compare numbers this small or some simple mistake I'm making with the compareTo method? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0Ewhatever` is still 0. They're all zero.

The reason that `E-932` even survives at all is because BigDecimal doesn't store *just* the number, it also knows what precision you're at; `0E-917` is 0, but at a certain precision.

As the spec states, `compareTo` checks the actual value and disregards the precision level, thus, all of these values are 100% equal to each other: They are all 0.

EDIT: To be clear, `0E-917` is not "an extremely small number". **It is zero**. That precision thing is effectively: Some calculation was `0.00000000....000000`, with 917 zeroes. It might be non-zero, but if it is, it has a non-zero digit only after *at least* 917 zeroes, and I didn't calculate that far. This, your BD instance has absolutely no way to know that (it just stored 918 zeroes).